# Android: Adapter's viewconvert is null, but I passed the correct layout

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

## Summary

First, I will explain the aim & the context of my problem. Then I will give you some generalities about how I implemented this feature. I will give you code with again some explanations. Finally, I will show you the output Java exception and ask you my question clearly.

---

## Aim & Context

I got some news from the Web thanks to a REST API, using some discriminate features. I want to display each news within my fragment's `ListView`.

## Implementation

### Explanations

1. I created the layout that modelizes a news. It contains an `ImageView` which will host the news' image, and some `TextView` which will host title, description, etc.
2. I created the `ArrayAdapter` which reuses this layout and populates its widgets.
3. I set up the REST API call to get JSONObject within a JSONArray. The latter is converted to a list of news objects. This list is used by the `ArrayAdapter` (see 2.).

### Sources

#### The `ArrayAdapter`

*NB: in the below code, `resource`'s value is set to `R.layout.world_news_list_item`, which is the layout that modelizes a news.*

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {
    private List<News> news;

    NewsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<News> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.news = objects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        News news = this.news.get(position);

        TextView textTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.world_news_item_title);
        textTitle.setText(news.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

#### Fragment's part: setting the `ArrayAdapter` for the fragment's `ListView`

*NB: in the below code, `R.layout.world_news_list_item`, which is the layout that modelizes a news, will be used within the `ArrayAdapter`'s constructor (see previously).*

```
list_view.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(context, R.layout.world_news_list_item, News.toArrayList(news)));
```

(written in the API REST call's callback on case of HTTP success (and response success)).

The fragment's layout contains a `ListView` which is inflated into `list_view`.

---

## Output exception & Question

### Output exception

When I start the fragment containing the `ListView`, this exception is output:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.xxx.xxx, PID: 31843
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.xxx.xxx.NewsAdapter.getView(NewsAdapter.java:25)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3189)
>           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2197)
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:824)
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:885)
>           at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1952)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2961)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20854)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20854)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:2492)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20854)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
>           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1171)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20854)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20854)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20854)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20854)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20854)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:945)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20854)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2919)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2606)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1743)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7780)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

### Question

Since `resource`'s value is set to `R.layout.world_news_list_item` (in the `ArrayAdapter`), which is the layout that modelizes a news, why is `convertView` `null` (in the `ArrayAdapter` too)?

**In other words: why should I must write something like `if(convertView == null) { inflate_world_news_list_item_layout();  }`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inflate **views for rows** of `ListView` yourself. That's why you need a code like this:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {
    private List<News> news;

    NewsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<News> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.news = objects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
        }

        News news = this.news.get(position);

        TextView textTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.world_news_item_title);
        textTitle.setText(news.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

All `ListView`s are like this in android and it is their power. You can customize each row with your own layout. Remember, in your case, you have overrided `getView`, so you need to do layout creation yourself as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter). In addition, you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#AdapterViews) too for using various adapters. Another great `ListView` tutorial can be found [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) too.

**Suggestion:**

Learn to use `RecyclerView`. It is more complex, but it is much more powerful than a simple `ListView`.

Comment: But I already gave the layout `world_news_list_item` (your `list_item`) as second parameter of the constructor of the `ArrayAdapter`. It is dedicated to that no? If not: what is its purpose?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler This happens because you have overrided `getView` method. If you have not, you didn't need to do so.

Comment: Maybe I'm misphrasing my question :-). For example, should I replace the given value of `resource` (which is my list item layout) by something else? I thought it was sufficient to make `convertView` automatically equalled to this same layout. Like if the constructor influenced the `getView` method. But obviously I am wrong.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler that will be sufficient if you don't want to override `getView` with you have. If your row layout have only 1 `TextView`, you can ignore overriding `getView` and framework automatically applies `ArrayAdapter` items to your layout. But if you need to customize your row layout by providing `getView` method, you need to inflate it yourself and 2nd parameter in creating `ArrayAdapter` is somehow irrelevant.

Comment: Ah okay! So I can set it to -1, 0, etc. no?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler keep it as is. or better provide another constructor for your class. check https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView too.